# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when matching all routes in Next.js middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I`m trying to redirect a user to specific pages based on role, using the following code in the middleware.ts file

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const token = await getToken({
        req: request,
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
    }) as any
    if (token !== null && token.user.role === "admin") {
        if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
            return NextResponse.next()
        }
        else {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/admin', request.url))
        }
    }
}
/* export const config = {
    matcher: [
     //   "/login",
     //  "/register",
     //  "/",
     //   "/admin"
    ],
} */
```

From what I understood from the docs it will run for all the routes, but I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<

[image]

However, if I include the matcher in the middleware file, it works as intended:

```
export const config = {
    matcher: [
       "/login",
       "/register",
       "/",
       "/admin"
    ],
}
```

Is there a fix for that error? Or just add all the pages to the matcher array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say a `middleware` without a `matcher` runs for every request, it includes requests for getting everything, including favicons, JavaScript files, CSS files... as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matching-paths).

You, in your `if` statement, you are saying, anything that does not start with `'/admin"`, should be redirected to `'/admin"`. So when the browser asks for those JavaScript files, you are redirecting it, which results in an HTML file being sent. This is the problem.

With the matcher, you are not blocking the browser from accessing the files that are needed to build the page, and scoping the middleware only on these paths:

```js
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/login", "/register", "/", "/admin"],
};
```

Comment: thank you , i got the reason now behind the error , adding `'/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'` to the matcher fixed it like from the docs .